# How to correctly remove the automatically added closing bracket when it is typed

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, java-6

in the `textPaneKeyTyped(java.awt.event.keyEvent evt)` method I wrote some code to automatically close brackets when the opening one is typed. I added some code for remove the closing bracket when the user type it in textPane, but it doesn't do anything

This is a working example:

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form NewJFrame */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        textPanel = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textPanel.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                textPanelKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(textPanel);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 254, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(27, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

private void textPanelKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
     Action action1 = new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textModel = (JTextPane) e.getSource();
            try {
                int position2 = textModel.getCaretPosition();
                textModel.getDocument().remove(position2, 1);
                textModel.getDocument().insertString(position2, ")", null);

            } catch (Exception e1) {}
        }

};
    Action action = new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int position = textModel.getCaretPosition();
                textModel.replaceSelection("()");
                textModel.setCaretPosition(position+1);
            }

    };

    String key =  "typed (";
    String key1 = "typed )";
    textPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key), key);
    textPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key1), key1);
    textPanel.getActionMap().put(key, action);
    textPanel.getActionMap().put(key1, action1);


}

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane textPanel;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

The code for the automatic closure of the brackets works..
The problem is for the replace of the closing bracket: it prints ')' just when before there's a '('. If I would be able to print the ')' at any time, how should I edit my code?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you display the value of `pos` when you do the removal ?

Comment: in the first line of the textPane, yes. In the second line it appears just if I close the bracket 2 times, like this: '(' ')' ')'. when type the second closing bracket it appears. In the third line when I type 3 times...

Comment: Also could you post a simple compilable and runnable example ? I don't think `private void textPaneprivate void textModelKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)` is a valid method signature .

Comment: Look at the post, I edited it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is never a good idea to block the usage of a KeyStroke. You never know when the ")" might need to be entered manually. Who cares if the user enters the ")". If it is not syntactically correct then they will eventually get a compile error. The smart user will realize that all then need to do is type "(" and the ")" will be entered for them.

However, if there is a situation when you do want to prevent the typing of a given character you would use `Key Bindings` NOT a KeyListener.

For example:

```
KeyStroke ignore = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(')');
textPane.getInputMap().put(ignore, "none");
```

For more information on `Key Bindings` read the Swig tutorial. I gave you a link in one of your previous questions. Keep the tutorial link handy for the basics. You will find a section on `How to Use Key Bindings` when you look at the table of contents ("trail") for the tutorial.

Also for your "(" Action you can just use:

```
textPane.replaceSelection("()");
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your useful tips! I edited my question with the new code, but it seems there's still an error: the ')' is print only if there's a '(' before.

Comment: `the ')' is print only if there's a '(' before` - that was your requirement. You wanted to automatically insert "()" and prevent the user from entering ")". I suggested is was not a good requirement and you should not even worry about the user typing ")". All you need is the custom Action for the "(" key to insert "()". In any case you still have a KeyListener. I have no idea why. I specifically stated you should **not use a KeyListener**.

Comment: Also, you didn't listen to my suggestion t use the replaceSelection() method. Your code is changing the way text input works. Normally if some text is selected and you type a character then the typed character will replace the selected text. However, you know have special code that won't replace the selected text whenever you type "(". This is an inconsistency.

Comment: KeyListener is added by default by Netbeans in the initComponent() method. Why i shouldn't use it? Moreover, I'd be able to print a ')' even if there's no '(' before, but, still, I want the insertion of '()' as well. Can you please check what's wrong in the action1 ? and why the project crash when i try to replace some text with a '('?  I know they're a lot of question but I cant get out of this. I also implemented the replaceSelection method.

Comment: `KeyListener is added by default by` - I doubt that. There is no reason to add a KeyListener. Certainly you would not create Action1 inside the KeyListener. You are doing something in the IDE to cause it to generate that code. The code you posted doesn't even compile. `Moreover, I'd be able to print a ')' even if there's no '(' before, but, still, I want the insertion of '()' as well` - You don't need to do anything!!! ")" is a valid character just like any other character on the keyboard. All you need is a single Action the handles the "(" key. Get rid of the second Action!